# dynamic rails host name for routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, routes, host

I'm doing this in application controller:

```
before_filter :set_app_host

def set_app_host
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "some url"
end
```

This is to have a dynamic host name that can show up in `link_to` helper method.
However this is not working, and the original host name is showing instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application_controller.rb

```
def default_url_options(options = nil)
  { :host => "example.com" }
end
```

From: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default_url_options

Comment: It's giving 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)' on every link_to

Comment: you included the options=nil as above?

Comment: Opps just noticed it! Worked, Thanks!